# Create multiple bundle web pack hot reload

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want to generate multiple bundle with hot reload with webpack :

For one I do :

```
 entry: [
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
        path.join(__dirname, 'app/main.js')
      ],
```

but for multiple I didn't find how to use this line : `'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',`

I try this :

```
entry: {
    //'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //This line is not accepted by webpack
    firstbundle : path.join(__dirname, 'client/first.js'),
    secondbundle : path.join(__dirname, 'client/second.js'),
    thirdbundle : path.join(__dirname, 'client/third.js')
  },
```

How I can add this line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass weboack-hot-middleware to each entry:

```
entry: {
    firstbundle : ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', path.join(__dirname, 'client/first.js')],
    secondbundle : ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', path.join(__dirname, 'client/second.js')],
    thirdbundle : ['webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', path.join(__dirname, 'client/third.js')]
},
```